# Atualizar uma ListView em um StatefulWidget filho Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

meu layout principal possui um aapBar, body e bottomNavigationBar
através do bottomNavigationBar eu atualizo o body com outras telas, que mostram um listview, no appBar da tela principal tenho um botão excluir tudo, não consigo atualizar o ListView da tela aberta em body...
os dados desta ListView vem de um FutureBuilder, como posso fazer isso?
DarPat: [Exemplo no DartPad](https://dartpad.dartlang.org/bcca305896b76f7f395710f40fbae51f)

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

final Color darkBlue = Color.fromARGB(255, 18, 32, 47);

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData.dark().copyWith(scaffoldBackgroundColor: darkBlue),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: MyWidget(),
    );
  }
}

class MyWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyWidgetState createState() => _MyWidgetState();
}

class _MyWidgetState extends State<MyWidget> {
  _menuSel(String itemText) {
    switch (itemText) {
      case "Marcar todos":
        print("ItemSel Marcar todos");
        break;
      case "Desmarcar todos":
        print("Excluindo registros do banco e atualizar liste view Tela1");
        //função exclui itens do bd atualizar Scaffold/ListView em Tela1 ou Tela2
        break;
    }
  }

  int _indiceNav = 0;

  List<String> itensMenu = ["Marcar todos", "Desmarcar todos"];

  List<Widget> telas = [
    Tela1(),
    Tela2(),
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
        title: Text("principal"),
        actions: <Widget>[
          IconButton(
            icon: Icon(Icons.search),
            onPressed: () {},
          ),
          PopupMenuButton<String>(
            onSelected: _menuSel,
            itemBuilder: (context) {
              return itensMenu.map((String item) {
                return PopupMenuItem<String>(
                  value: item,
                  child: Text(item),
                );
              }).toList();
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
      body: telas[_indiceNav],
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
          currentIndex: _indiceNav,
          onTap: (indice) {
            print("pressionado $indice");
            setState(() {
              _indiceNav = indice;
            });
          },
          items: [
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
                title: Text("Tela1"), icon: Icon(Icons.alarm)),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
                title: Text("Tela2"), icon: Icon(Icons.list)),
          ]),
    );
  }
}

class Tela1 extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _Tela1State createState() => _Tela1State();
}

class _Tela1State extends State<Tela1> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Text("TEla 1");
    //return Scaffold(body: FutureBuilder... ListView...);
  }
}

class Tela2 extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _Tela2State createState() => _Tela2State();
}

class _Tela2State extends State<Tela2> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Text("TEla 2");
    //return Scaffold(body: FutureBuilder... ListView...);
  }
}
```

No projeto principal, Tela1, e Tela2 são arquivos separados.
Resumindo, preciso acessar métodos e atualizar as telas abertas em body!

Comment: Sua pergunta está um pouco confusa e no teu exemplo não existe nenhuma `ListView`... Só para ver se entendi, você possuí um `BottomNavigator` com 2 abas, cada qual com sua respectiva `ListView` e quando clicar no botão "Excluir todos", quer que seja limpa a `ListView` da aba que está sendo exibida, é isso?

Comment: Exatamente, a lista está sendo preenchida em um FutureBuilder de dados de uma API, não coloquei esta parte do código pra não ficar muito extenso.. está tudo funcionando, inclusive a exclusão dos dados do BD, preciso apenas atualizar a tela onde está a listview.

Answer (score 0):

Criei um exemplo para você que pode ser testado no [DartPad](https://dartpad.dartlang.org/)....

Como você não nos mostrou como está seu código completo, tente aplicar meu exemplo ao seu caso, que deve resolver:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

final Color darkBlue = Color.fromARGB(255, 18, 32, 47);

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyApp({ Key key }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  final List<String> list = ["Item 2", "Item 2", "Item 3", "Item 4", "Item 5"];

  Future<List<String>> getData(){
    return Future.value(list);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData.dark().copyWith(scaffoldBackgroundColor: darkBlue),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: FutureBuilder(
          future: getData(),
          builder: (_, data){
            return ListView.builder(
              itemCount: list.length,
              itemBuilder: (_, int index){
                return Text(list[index].toString());
              }
            );
          },
        ),
        floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
          child: Icon(Icons.close), 
          onPressed: (){
            setState((){
              list.clear();
            });
          },
        )
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**Observação**

Esse código exemplo meu, é relativo a uma tela apenas, então terá que aplicar nas duas

Comment: esqueceu de coloca o link do gist no dartpad.

Comment: Não esqueci, eu não coloco link do Gist :D sendo que basta a pessoa copiar o código e colar no Dartpad que funciona certinho...

Comment: Entendi, beleza.